# Python and pip proxy remove

Tags: python-3.x, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

When I try to run Oracle Cloud's oci-cli, it tries to look for a proxy that I had previously configured but no longer need. When I try to install a package with "pip" or run a command it shows me the following errors(1) where it is evident that it tries to look for the ip of the previously set proxy. I have tried to change it by setting the env HTTP_PROXY="" but it still does not work.

I attach the logs.

pip error:

pip install manager

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002074060D9D0>, 'Connection to 10.130.1.50 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/manager/

ERROR: Operation cancelled by user

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 23.2.1 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

OCI CLI Erorr:

oci cli

oci.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: (MaxRetryError("OCIConnectionPool(host='identity.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /20160918/regions (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<oci.base_client.OCIConnection object at 0x0000015519AD6370>, 'Connection to 10.130.1.50 timed out. (connect timeout=10.0)'))"), 'Request Endpoint: GET https://identity.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com/20160918/regions See https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdk_troubleshooting.htm for help troubleshooting this error, or contact support and provide this full error message.')

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

I have changed the proxy on my Windows machines and from the pip configuration files

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to StackOverflow. I would suggest going to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and understand how to write good and concise questions. Visit: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server for your answer.